# When my popup opens why does it not show the full contents of treeview?

Tags: wpf, popup, treeview, scrollbar, scrollviewer

I have a `TreeView` within a `Popup`. The idea is that the user will select from the `TreeView` and be able to view any opened nodes.  Here's the code:

```
<Popup PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=TBXProjection}" Style="{StaticResource ProjPopupStyle}" VerticalOffset="27" HorizontalOffset="-262" Margin="0,0,465,279" Name="PopupProjection" AllowsTransparency="True" Placement="Top">
    <Grid>
        <Border BorderThickness="2" Background="DodgerBlue" BorderBrush="DodgerBlue" Padding="0" CornerRadius="6">
            <ScrollViewer Height="275" Name="scrollViewer1" Width="260" BorderBrush="Black" Background="DodgerBlue">
                <TreeView Name="dirTree" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource xmldata}, XPath=.}" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard" SelectedItemChanged="dirTree_SelectedItemChanged"/>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Popup>
```

Here is what it's doing. Here is what I need it to do.

[image: Here is what the popup/treeview is doing][image: Here is what it's supposed to do.]

I realize the user can scroll down manually and get the info, but if they select (for example Wyoming) its with the intent to then select another child. The scroll should automatically open down so that their selections can be made.

Can someone help direct me to the correct property I need to tweak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know any property that does what you want.

However you can use [BrinIntoView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.bringintoview.aspx) method on last of the [TreeViewItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeviewitem.aspx) you want to be visible. Every time when you open a node, check if last child element is visible, and if not use a method that I linked. Here's a modification of your code that should obtain your goal:

XAML part:

```
<TreeView Name="dirTree" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource xmldata}, XPath=.}" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"
                                      VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard" SelectedItemChanged="dirTree_SelectedItemChanged" TreeViewItem.Expanded="ShowMyLastChild"/>
```

C# part:

```
    private void ShowMyLastChild(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((TreeViewItem)((TreeViewItem)(e.Source)).Items.GetItemAt(((TreeViewItem)(e.Source)).Items.Count - 1)).BringIntoView();
    }
```

In the code above I've added attached event to TreeView which will occur every time it's child node is expanded. The event handler checks for the last child node in expanded child node and brings it into view. This way you have it done regardless of data source.

Please ask, if you need any further assistance, I'll be glad to help.

Comment: The treeview is bound to an xml document. I already have a SelectedItemChanged that checks if the selection is a final child node. here is the code: `code` XmlElement i = (XmlElement)dirTree.SelectedItem;
            if (i.Name.Equals("Zone"))
            { `code`  I'm having a difficult time trying to find a simple example of using BringIntoView on the SelectedItem in order to make this work.  Any examples would help.

Comment: I've editted my answer, I hope this will do the trick for you.

Comment: I get _Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.TreeView' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem'._ which is a shame. Guess I'll keep looking, but thanks a lot for all your efforts.

Comment: Thats strange, I've checked it to be sure. Here's mine test project, maybe it will help you: http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=g1d6da7ffa7a192499992678455f663155412090f8